# Float element with negative right margin

Tags: html, css

I found in Susy something like:

[online link at plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FljintOhQx80M5W9XnNL?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    div {
      width: 20%;
      height: 40px;
      float: left;

      margin-right: -100%;
    }
    .a {
      background: red;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .b {
      background: yellow;
      margin-left: 20%;
    }
    .c {
      background: green;
      margin-left: 40%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="c"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why it happens. Why do float divs line up one after another?

It seems to me it must look something like, back to front:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/AQqn6.png]

and

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/PUyBc.png]

Maybe I forgot an important thing about float? Thank you.

Comment: It seems The left outer edge of a floated element must be to the left of the left outer edge of a left-floating element that occurs earlier in the document's source. http://plnkr.co/edit/0EkhRPGfHgsJTQR33PmY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

By you [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUyBc.png) I think you need something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    div {
      width: 20%;
      height: 40px;
      float: left;
      margin-left:20%;
    }
    .a {
      background: green;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .b {
      background: yellow;
    }
    .c {
      background: red;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="c"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to know http://plnkr.co/edit/afX2xDaPt01R9BSc4E52?p=preview Why doesn't yellow box going outside html page in second case? I supposed 2nd yellow box moves to the left because 2nd red box has margin-right: -100px.

Comment: It seems The left outer edge of a floated element must be to the left of the left outer edge of a left-floating element that occurs earlier in the document's source. http://plnkr.co/edit/0EkhRPGfHgsJTQR33PmY?p=preview

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? If you share, may be I could help you.